# Can scientific discovery be used to short stock without being considered insider trading?

Tags: short-selling

Let's say you make a scientific discovery that destroys the business model of a publicly traded company, for example you find a way to factor large integers in polynomial time (destroying the business of RSA encryption companies), or you discover how to build an antigravity drive (destroying the business model of SpaceX etc.). Can you legally short the stock of the companies whose business model your discovery destroys, before patenting and/or publishing your discovery? Or would that be considered insider trading, even though you don't have any inside information about those companies per se?

Comment: Don’t know why this is downvoted, it is an interesting question. It is illegal to trade on the basis of material non-public information that you obtained as a result of privatised access as an insider to a company. If you obtained this information without link to the company as anyone else could have in principle legitimately obtained then trade away.

Comment: I don't see how your example would constitute inside information.  You made a discovery.  The way that discovery may impact another business is an untested hypothesis at this point.  I don't think you have anything to worry about...except your hypothesis being wrong ;)